# Merge on one key after the other

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I often end up with the following situation. I have a dataframe with two IDs

```
A = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a', 'a1'], [2, None, 'a2'], [3,'c', 'a3'], [4,'None', 'a3'], [None, 'e', 'a3'], ['None', 'None', 'None']], columns = ['id1', 'id2', 'colA'])

    id1   id2  colA
0     1     a    a1
1     2  None    a2
2     3     c    a3
3     4  None    a3
4  None     e    a3
5  None  None  None
```

and I have another dataframe with additional info I want to add to the first dataframe

```
B = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a', 'b1', 'c1'], [2, 'b', 'b2', 'c2'], [3,'c', 'b3', 'c3'], [4, 'd', 'b4', 'c4'], [5, 'e', 'b5', 'c5'], [6, 'e', 'b5', 'c5']], columns = ['id1', 'id2', 'colB', 'colC'])
Out[15]: 
id1 id2 colB colC
0    1   a   b1   c1
1    2   b   b2   c2
2    3   c   b3   c3
3    4   d   b4   c4
4    5   e   b5   c5
5    6   e   b5   c5
```

I want to merge on id1, like this 
    A.merge(B, how='left', on='id1')

```
      id1 id2_x  colA id2_y colB colC
0     1     a    a1     a   b1   c1
1     2  None    a2     b   b2   c2
2     3     c    a3     c   b3   c3
3     4  None    a3     d   b4   c4
4  None     e    a3   NaN  NaN  NaN
5  None  None  None   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

This is close to what I want. However for the failed lookups (that is when id1 is not available) I would like to merge on id2, so the result looks like

```
      id1 id2_x  colA id2_y colB colC
0     1     a    a1     a   b1   c1
1     2  None    a2     b   b2   c2
2     3     c    a3     c   b3   c3
3     4  None    a3     d   b4   c4
4  None     e    a3   NaN   b5   c5
5  None  None  None   NaN  NaN  NaN
```

What's the best way to achieve this? Note I don't really want 2 id2 columns in the result and id2 may have duplicates.

Comment: Would it not be better to do `A.combine_first(B)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html). But it fill last row too.

```
 print df
    id1 id2_x  colA id2_y colB colC
0     1     a    a1     a   b1   c1
1     2  None    a2     b   b2   c2
2     3     c    a3     c   b3   c3
3     4  None    a3     d   b4   c4
4  None     e    a3   NaN  NaN  NaN
5  None  None  None   NaN  NaN  NaN


df = df.fillna(B)
print df
    id1 id2_x  colA id2_y colB colC
0     1     a    a1     a   b1   c1
1     2  None    a2     b   b2   c2
2     3     c    a3     c   b3   c3
3     4  None    a3     d   b4   c4
4  None     e    a3   NaN   b5   c5
5  None  None  None   NaN   b5   c5
```

As EdChum mentioned in comments, next solution is use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html), but output is different:

```
print A.combine_first(B)
   colA colB colC   id1   id2
0    a1   b1   c1     1     a
1    a2   b2   c2     2     b
2    a3   b3   c3     3     c
3    a3   b4   c4     4  None
4    a3   b5   c5     5     e
5  None   b5   c5  None  None
```

Difference is:

```
In [142]: %timeit A.combine_first(B)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.44 ms per loop

In [143]: %timeit A.merge(B, how='left', on='id1').fillna(B)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.89 ms per loop
```